# How do I prevent an updating search bar to cancel a previous request when a new one is made?

Tags: angular

I have a search bar that does a search for events based on an id.  As more numbers are typed in the search bar it is continuously updating to search for events based on the partial id typed.  So when I stop typing, my newest results are getting updated by the previous requests.

Example.  I search by typing 12345.

Results are shown for 12345

Then it gets updated by results of 1234.

Then it gets updated by results of 123.

Update:

'''

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  events: Events[]
  triggered = false

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.events = <Events[]>[]
  }

  searchForEvents(searchTerm) {
    this.eventService.getEventsByPartialId(searchTerm)
      .subscribe(data => this.events = data)
    this.triggered = true
  }
}
```

'''

Comment: you need to add your actual code....

Comment: Use switchMap. See an example here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#http

Comment: What have you implemented so far? Do you have some sample code to work with?

Comment: Note that this happens precisely because you do NOT cancel a previous request when a new one is made. If the request for 1234 was cancelled when you send the request for 12345, then the results of 1234 would never come, and wouldn't replace the results of 12345.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should get what you're looking for if you use the standard RxJS operators used for these specific scenarios, like:

1. `map` - To transform the `keyup` event into a text that could be used for the search.
2. `debounceTime` - To wait until x ms before doing something. So if the user changes anything within those x ms, it won't be accounted for.
3. `distinctUntilChanged` - To check if the value has actually changed within x ms.
4. `tap` - To set the loading state before actually making an API call.
5. `switchMap` - To switch the context of the Observable to the result of the `http.get` call.
6. `catchError` - To handle the errors coming in from API, just in case there are any.

---

Give this a try:

```
import { Component, Injectable, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, fromEvent, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, distinctUntilChanged, debounceTime, tap, switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SearchService } from './search.service';


@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})
export class AppComponent {
  model: Observable<any>;
  searching = false;
  searchFailed = false;
  searchField$: Observable<any>;
  @ViewChild('input', { static: true }) input: ElementRef;

  constructor(private _service: SearchService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.searchField$ = fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, `keyup`);
    this.model = this.searchField$.pipe(
      map(event => event.target.value),
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => this.searching = true),
      switchMap(term =>
        this._service.search(term).pipe(
          tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
          catchError(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return of([]);
          }))
      ),
      tap(() => this.searching = false)
    );
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-github-search-with-debounce-and-all-that-rxjs-jazz?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.