# send search final word after some time( like 1000 ms after word completion) of completion of typing

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to send only one search api request after some time of final search word. for example 1000 ms after I type 'hello' . It should sent only one request.
I am using Rxjs, Angular 6.

I have tried some code but not able to achieve desired output.

Here you can find stackblitz demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbuxi1)

Comment: Check **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57116480/2622292)** out. It's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Raman you can call API on focus out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular approach would be to use `rxjs` `debounceTime` piped to the `valueChanges` observable of the reactive `FormControl` as in the example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-debounce-form-control

The logic is to get the reference to your input using `FormControl` and subscribe to the `valueChanges` method and pipe a `debounceTime` to fire the callback method only if not fired in a specific interval.

```
this.searchControl.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(2000))
.subscribe(res => {
    //your API call
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Istead of the observable you can just use [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Maybe like this:

```
timeout = null; // at the top of your component

onKeyUp(searchString) {
 if (this.timeout) {
  clearTimeout(this.timeout) 
  // clear last Timeout so you dont get multiple Events
 }

 this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  // do your stuff
  console.log(searchString)
 }, 1000);
}
```